# Is there anything like "Run" in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: browser, text-editors, sublime-text-2

Is there a way to launch a page in browsers from Sublime Text 2 ?
Like Run in Notepad++?

Answer (score 4):

Tools->Build System->New Build System.

With this you can run an app and load a page, etc. You can also specify those rules directly in your project file.

Here's a reference to help you get started:
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html